# DataGrip - Compile invalid objects (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, datagrip

I'm  trying to **'compile invalid objects'** in **Oracle procedures** using **Datagrip**. I didn't find any option for it. Any advice? Is this even possible?

It was possible to do it in the past, below (DataGrip 2016.2):

[image: Recompiling invalid objects in DataGrip 2016.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Recompile" action was just moved into the "Database Tools" submenu:

[image: the Recompile item was moved into Database Tools submenu]

It could be omitted in one of 2021.2.x versions but in the version 2021.2.2 it does present.